# Can lead be divined?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic

Many divination spells—*detect* spells in particular—say that they are blocked by any amount of lead.

But what if the thing you want to divine is in fact *made* of lead? Could that thing be divined?

If the caster were trying to detect the thing made of lead, it doesn't seem like it could block *itself* (because the caster's spell doesn't need to penetrate the thing), but I can't seem to find a rules reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Even spells blocked by lead can discern details about and locate appropriate objects made from lead

Spells like the 0-level Sor/Wiz spell [*detect magic*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#detect-magic) [div] (*Player's Handbook* 219) "can penetrate barriers, but 1 foot of stone, 1 inch of common metal, a thin sheet of lead, or 3 feet of wood or dirt blocks [them]," and spells like the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*locate object*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#locate-object) [div] (*PH* 249) are "blocked by even a thin sheet of lead." Thus, even if the magic item or object envisioned, respectively, is *composed* of lead, the item's aura will be perceived or the object will be located. (This also means, for example, the spell *detect magic* can be used to perceive magical auras *on* woodpiles or mounds of dirt, but not magic auras *buried beneath* those woodpiles or mounds of dirt!)

However, if a magic item that's made of lead blocks line of effect to magic auras beyond it or contains within it, for whatever reason, *other* magic auras, those magic auras won't be detected by the spell *detect magic*. Further, if some jerk hides the lead object envisioned inside a lead box, the spell *locate object* will be unable to locate the envisioned object.

Answer (score 5):

If the lead is between your spell and the target, then it blocks. If the target is the lead, it shouldn't matter. Think of it like your eyes. If you are looking at a lead wall you'll find nothing, unless you are looking for a lead wall.

Quoting from the player's handbook *Locate Object* description on page 249:

> The spell is blocked by even a thin sheet of  lead.

And again from *Message* on page 253:

> Magical silence, 1 foot of stone, 1 inch of common metal (or a thin sheet of lead), or 3 feet of wood or dirt blocks the spell.

In short, spells that can be blocked are blocked if the path they take (Line of sight, touch, cone, etc.) is interrupted by an impassable obstruction.

If casting *Locate Object* on a target thin sheet of lead, with no obstacles in between caster and target, then that object would be *Located*.

Comment: I understand this is how normal senses work, but mechanically there does not seem to be support or contradiction to this as far as I could find. It matters on the surface whether the lead absorbs or reflects in order to do its shielding.

Comment: Absorption and reflection are not indicated in the spell either. It's at least as well supported that you find the thing by smell, where reflection would be meaningless.

Answer (score -3):

Lead can be divined as long as it is not behind a barrier made of lead.

Comment: And you know this how?

Comment: Hi Waylander, and welcome to the site. Please check out our [tour] to see how we work here. We expect answers to back themselves up with rules citations where applicable -- we can't take people just at their word.